# How to write a method that sorts an ArrayList in java using a generic Comparable type

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparable

I am trying to write a method to sort an array of integers.

The method must utilize the `Comparable` interface. I've designed a test case and attempted to write a solution.

Expected:

```
Enter 10 integers: 3 4 12 7 3 4 5 6 4 7
The sorted numbers are 3 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 7 12
```

Actual:

```
Enter 10 integers: 1
Enter 10 integers: 2
Enter 10 integers: 34
Enter 10 integers: 4
Enter 10 integers: 3
Enter 10 integers: 2
Enter 10 integers: 1
Enter 10 integers: 4
Enter 10 integers: 5
Enter 10 integers: 6
The sorted numbers are: 3 5 4 1 2 2 1 4 5 6
```

My attempt

```
public class Test2 {
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter 10 integers: ");
            int integer    = input.nextInt();
            array.add(integer);
        }
        sort(array);
        System.out.print("The sorted numbers are ");
        for(int i = 0; i <= array.size()-1; i++){
            System.out.print(array.get(i)+" ");
        }
    }

    public static <E extends Comparable <E>> void sort(ArrayList<E> list) {
        int n = list.size();
    
        for(int  i = 1; i < n-1; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) {
                if(list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i+1)) < 0) {
                    E temp = list.get(i);
                    list.set(j, list.get(j+1));
                    list.set(j + 1, temp);
                }
            }
         }
     }
}
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work in the same way, as you can assign the value to the element of an ***array***.

With a ***list*** you have to use method [`set()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#set(int,E)):

```
list.set(j + 1, temp);
```

Also, avoid using concrete types like `ArrayList` for method parameters and variables, write your code against interfaces like `List`. Now, your method `sort()` is limited to accept only instances `ArrayList` and not able to deal with a `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the *logic* is wrong, that repeated swapping will not necessarily sort all.

The code does not give any assurrance to cover all pairs needing swapping:

```
public static <E extends Comparable <E>> void sort(List<E> list) {
    int n = list.size();
    for (int  i = 1; i < n-1; i++) { // n-2 i's
        for (int j = 0; j < n-1-i; j++) { // for all i: n-1-i
            if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i+1)) < 0) {
                Collections.swap(i, j+1);
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

It assumes that the elements after n-1-i will be sorted later.
Especially the last element i == n-1 seems not be treated.

More trustworthy:

```
public static <E extends Comparable <E>> void sort(List<E> list) {
    int n = list.size();
    // INVARIANT list[0, i> is sorted
    for (int  i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // INVARIANT list[0, i> is sorted

        // INVARIANT list[0, j> is sorted
        // INVARIANT list[j, i> is sorted
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            // INVARIANT list[0, j> is sorted
            // INVARIANT list[j, i> is sorted
            if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(j)) < 0) {
                Collections.swap(i, j);
                // And greater j's are unsorted w.r.t. j
            }
            // INVARIANT list[j+1, i> is sorted
            // INVARIANT list[0, j+1> is sorted
        }
        // INVARIANT list[0, i+1> is sorted
     }
     // INVARIANT list[0, n> is sorted
 }
```

You could check out *pre-conditions, post-conditions, loop-variants, invariants* and *proofs*.

The complexity (of both) is **O(n²)** which could be bettered, as 100² is already 10_000 (5_000 loop steps).

Answer (score -3):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Exercise19_09 {
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter 10 integers: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            int integer    = input.nextInt();
            array.add(integer);
        }
        sort(array);
        System.out.print("The sorted numbers are ");
        for(int i = 0; i <= array.size()-1; i++){
            System.out.print(array.get(i)+" ");
        }
    }

    public static <E extends Comparable <E>> void sort(ArrayList<E> list){
        int n = list.size();
    
        for(int  i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
                if(list.get(j).compareTo(list.get(j+1)) > 0){
                    E temp = list.get(j);
                    list.set(j, list.get(j+1));
                    list.set(j + 1, temp);

                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The general advice given on Stack Overflow about answers is about how the author can make them useful for future readers. I've not downvoted, but a couple of people have. Perhaps their advice would be that some explanatory text would be excellent. Could you add some in?